# What is a minimal set $S\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that $S\cap k\Bbb N$ is non-empty for all $k\in\Bbb N$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In other words, $S$ must contain at least one multiple of every natural number.

Clearly $S$ must be infinite, since otherwise $k=1+\max S$ violates our condition.

The best example I can do is this: Let $p_1,p_2,p_3,\dots$ is an enumeration of the primes.

Let $S_1 = \{p_1,p_1p_2,p_1p_2p_3,\dots\} =  \{\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i:n\in\Bbb N\} $.

For $r\geq 2$ let $S_r=\{q^r:q\in S_1\}$.

Let $S=\bigcup_{r=1}^{\infty}S_r$.

This fits our condition because let $k$ be any natural number. Then it has a prime decomposition $k=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_n^{r_n}$. Let $r=\max\{r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n\}$. Then $k$ divides $p_1^rp_2^r\cdots p_n^r$, so $k\in S_r$.

This construction is ad hoc. So, is there a smaller set $S$?

Edit: For $S\subseteq\Bbb N$ define $d_S(N)=\frac{1}{N}|S\cap\{1,2,3,\dots,N\}|$. If $\lim_{N\to\infty}d_S(N)$ exists then call it the density of $S$ and denote it by $d_S$. Say a set $S$ is smaller than $T$ if $d_S<d_T$, or if $d_S(N)<d_T(N)$ for very large $N$.

Comment: What do you mean by *smaller*? These are all going to be countably infinite sets.

Comment: You could just take the factorials. I don't know whether this counts as "smaller" than your $S$, but it's certainly simpler.

Comment: I edited my post with a definition of "smaller".

Comment: I think those are good size measures. The factorials already have density $0$ (right?), so we will have to look at the asymptotic behaviour to compare sets.

Comment: The set of all number of the form $\underbrace{n^{n^{n^{\cdots^n}}}}_{n^{n^n}}$ is fairly small ... even among all those density zero sequences.

Comment: Curious where this question arose?  My intuition tells me that you can construct a sequence $ S_n $ with density approaching zero, so that the answer to the existence question would be negative.

Comment: Wait a minute!  By the prime number theorem, your set has density zero!  So the only way to improve is to have faster convergence to zero density.

Comment: It's already been established that density $0$ is achievable (say, factorials). Is there a deep reason why the class of functions $\{d_S(\bullet)\,:\, \forall k,\ S\cap k\Bbb N\}$ should have minimal elements with respect to the order $f\preceq g\iff \exists N,\forall n\ge N,\ f(n)\le g(n)$?

Comment: @Gae.S. Of course not. After all, we can always remove finitely many termns from the sequence.

Comment: I think we can make $S$ extremely small. Let $a_n$ be an integer sequence which approaches $\infty$ arbitrarily fast. Then the set $S=\{a_n!\}$ has zero density, and converges there arbitrarily fast, no?